# What is the name of the Visual Studio CommandBar for the HTML right-click menu?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

It's (relatively) common knowledge that the right-click menu for the code editing context, when developing a Visual Studio add-in, is the one called `"Code Window"`:

```
var CodeRightClickMenu = ((CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars)["Code Window"];
```

However, adding items to that menu does not show them when right-clicking in an HTML-like (i.e. razor view or webforms .ascx or .aspx).  What is the name of the CommandBar for the HTML editor's right-click menu?

Answer (score 0):

According to [digging](http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2012/07/29/visual-studio-addins-adding-items-to-context-menus/) done by [James Wiseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144491/james-wiseman/), the name of the HTML editor's right-click menu is `"HTML Context"`. It's only used for true HTML though (like the HTML parts of a Razor view, or .html files).  The menus for other, related things all end in "Context" as well:

```
HTML Context
ASPX Context
ASPX Code Context
ASPX VB Code Context
```